# Getting auxiliary assumptions from a conclusion

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the book I'm reading they say they want to deduce $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ from $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$.

Now, as far as I understood, $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is an assumption, and $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ is the conclusion.

This conclusion can apparently be taken apart to get auxiliary assumptions. This is done by taking the antecedent of $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ as an auxiliary assumption. Then they take another auxiliary assumption (but from where I do not know because it doesn't say) to have p as an auxiliary assumption.

My question is this: if an antecedent has been taken as an auxiliary assumption, can it be used again to take another auxiliary assumption? So for example, from $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ we take $(p \rightarrow q)$ as an auxiliary assumption, and is now in the assumption collection. But can we now take p from $(p \rightarrow q)$, or can we only take it from $(p \rightarrow r)$.

Second question is, can we only take the antecedent as an auxiliary assumption? So q can never be an auxiliary assumption?

Comment: My help to know wht is "your book", or at least to know if you are working with *Natural Deduction* or in an *Hilbert-style* proof system (i.e.axioms+rules). With the first case, you can make more assumptions, and you can discharge them according to the rules you are using, in order to have : $A \vdash B$.

Comment: But specifically about your example, are you sure of it ? With $p = T$ and $q = r = F$, we have that $ p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is $T$, while $(p \rightarrow q) \land (p \rightarrow r)$ is $F$, so you cannot derive the second from the first.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you're absolutely right, I made a mistake: it shouldn't have been conjunction, but implication! I made the edits in my post.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - the book doesn't mention Hilbert-style proof, it is a chapter about natural deduction.

Comment: Now,the solution: yes, you must assume the premise $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ and two temporary assumptions: $p \rightarrow q$ and $p$; with $p$, by $\rightarrow$-elim you get $q$ from $(p \rightarrow q)$ and $q \rightarrow r$ from the premise. Now, using $q$, you detach $r$ from $q \rightarrow r$. Now we must reassemble the result: with $r$ under assumption $p$ get $p \rightarrow r$, using the rule $\rightarrow$-intro, and discharge $p$. Then use $\rightarrow$-intro again, gettin $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$, discharging the second temporary assumption.

Comment: And can we use a temporary assumption to derive another temporary assumption? So, $p \rightarrow q$ is made a temporary assumption from $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$. Is it allowed to take another temporary assumption from this temporary assumption?
 
And what do you mean 'discharge p'?

Comment: Pleas please please, which book are you using (and on which page are you)

Comment: @Willemien I'm using Logica voor informatica, page 52

Comment: @Garth - you said that you are studying natural deduction; in ND, some rules allows you to "discharge" an (occurence of an) assumption: this means to "cancel" the said (occurence of) the assumption form the list of assumptions. E.g.the rule $\rightarrow$-intro works as follow: given a proof of $\psi$ from $\phi$ and a set $\Gamma$ of other premisses, we may immediately infer $\phi \rightarrow \psi$. This conclusion does not depend on $\phi$ but only on the other premisses in $\Gamma$. In applying the rule we "discharge" the assumption $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard natural deductions systems, you can make any new assumption you want to at any time. (Often this is called the 'Rule of Assumptions' or the like.)

Of course if you are trying to show that some *given* assumptions $A, B, \ldots, C$  entail a given conclusion $E$, then any additional assumptions you make along the way -- auxiliary assumptions made "for the sake of argument" -- will need to be discharged.

For example if the conclusion $E$ is of the form $p \to q$, it will often help *temporarily* to assume along the way $p$, deduce $q$, and then at the end discharge that additional assumption to infer as wanted $p \to q$ from just the original premisses.  For another example, if the conclusion $E$ is of the form $\neg p$, it may well help *temporarily* to assume along the way $p$, deduce a contradiction, and then at the end discharge the assumption we've reduced to absurdity, and infer as wanted $\neg p$ from just the original premisses.

But yes, it is liberty hall in natural deduction systems -- assume whatever you want, whenever you want, keeping track as you go of what assumptions are in play. Though of course what you deduce will then depend on not just the original premisses (if any) but on any additional assumptions in play, until such time as they get discharged using a rule like Conditional Proof or Reductio ad Absurdum.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!